# How can I update a react view if a mysql database value changes?

Tags: reactjs

In a React app I insert a value to a mysql database. I want to automatically reload the view, once that value in the database changes.
Between the insert and the change can be a timeframe of an hour.
I know, something is working with Firebase database, but I don't want to use this.
I don't want to reload the view every x seconds.

Is there a way to to create a kind of listener?

Comment: Do you insert your new values to database with post request from frontend?

Comment: yes I do. Just a simple `axios.post()`

Comment: So basically you can use useEffect to update your view with callback when you trigger your post request

Comment: I'm not sure, if I need to rephrase my question, but I need to trigger rather on a `.get()`

Comment: Probably you want to use either long polling or websockets.